# Looking for The Closest Value in HashMap but not lesser than

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I want to search for a key in a hashmap and find the nearest one to that key but the return key  should not be lesser than the input value even if the different is closer , it should return a higher closer value instead.

example if I were to search for value 10, it should return me key 12 instead of 9. or if i search value 13 it should return me 17 and not 12

I have tried several method but i still unable to achieve what i wanted. anyone has clue on this?

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> list = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList>();
    list.put(17,null);
    list.put(7,null);
    list.put(9,null);
    list.put(12,null);

            public int findCloestButNotLess(int value, Map<Integer, ArrayList> map) {

            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            int nearest = 0;
            for (int key : map.keySet()) {
                int diff = Math.abs(value - key);

                if (diff < minDiff) {

                    nearest = key;
                    minDiff = diff;
                }

            }
            return nearest;
        }
```

Comment: If order is important you should use a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to sort the keys and return the smallest entry that's greater or equal to the key you're looking for. Note that I changed the signature to return a `java.lang.Integer` instead of a primitive `int` so that `null` can be returned if all the keys are less than the search value:

```
public static Integer findClosestButNotLess(int value, Map<Integer, ?> map) {
    return map.keySet()
              .stream()
              .sorted().filter(k -> k >= value)
              .findFirst()
              .orElse(null);
}
```

**EDIT:**
In retrospect, sorting is a relatively expensive operation, and you'd potentially be wasting resources by sorting parts of the stream you don't care about. Instead, you could filter out the keys you don't care about first and just take the minimal remaining key:

```
public static Integer findClosestButNotLess(int value, Map<Integer, ?> map) {
    return map.keySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(k -> k >= value)
              .min(Comparator.naturalOrder())
              .orElse(null);
}
```